# How to test the app invite of Android with out launching my app in google playstore?

Tags: android, google-app-invites

Hi i am working around APP INVITE provided by google. I would like to test the invite functionality with out launching to play store. Help me how to test app invite?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by submitting your app to the Play Store under an Alpha or Beta build. You will need to create a Google Plus community for the testers to join. It takes a little work but works out great.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: Google just made Alpha/Beta testing much easier.  See this article among many that covered this story: http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/30/google-play-now-lets-android-app-developers-offer-open-betas-closed-betas-using-only-email-addresses/